# What does this statement mean in C?

Tags: c, gsl

I am trying to understand the piece of code written in C and not sure I understand it fully.

Here is the function written in C:

```
int
gsl_multimin_diff (const gsl_multimin_function * f,
                   const gsl_vector * x, gsl_vector * g)
{
  size_t i, n = f->n;

  double h = GSL_SQRT_DBL_EPSILON;


  gsl_vector * x1 = gsl_vector_alloc (n);  /* FIXME: pass as argument */

  gsl_vector_memcpy (x1, x);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      double fl, fh;

      double xi = gsl_vector_get (x, i);
      double dx = fabs(xi) * h;

      if (dx == 0.0) dx = h;    

     (x1, i, xi + dx);
      fh = GSL_MULTIMIN_FN_EVAL(f, x1);

      gsl_vector_set (x1, i, xi - dx);
      fl = GSL_MULTIMIN_FN_EVAL(f, x1);

      gsl_vector_set (x1, i, xi);
      gsl_vector_set (g, i, (fh - fl) / (2.0 * dx));
    }

  gsl_vector_free (x1);

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```

There is a line 14 in this code, which has this: `(x1, i, xi + dx)`
What does it do? 
For referenc:
x1 is the pointer to the function that allocates memory for a newly created vector. 
i - loop iterator
xi - returning an element from the vector at position i
dx is just a value.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure there's no `gsl_vector_set` missing just in front of it?

Comment: Yes, looks like the gsl_vector_set was deleted by error.

Comment: Well, this is from the gsl source. Unless I deleted it by accident some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's something missing there. It should be function arguments. Otherwise it's a no-op - (x1, i, xi + dx) is a valid expression in C, but one that doesn't do anything. It just mentions x1, then mentions i, then mentions the sum of xi and dx.